# Code a SQL Server stored procedure to update vc_statusID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I coded a stored procedure called `vc_FinishVidCast` that accepts an `int` as an input parameter that will be a `vc_VidCastID` that we will need to mark as finished. The act of finishing a `VidCast` means we must change its `EndDateTime` to be the current Date and Time (think `GetDate()`) and change the `vc_StatusID` to the `vc_StatusID` for the ‘Finished’ status.

```
alter procedure vc_FinishVidCast 
    (@vidCastID int, @finished int)     
as 
begin
    update vc_VidCast 
    set vc_StatusID = @finished
    where vc_VidCastID = @vidCastID
end 
go

exec vc_FinishVidCast '859', '2'

DECLARE @newVC INT

INSERT INTO vc_VidCast (VidCastTitle, StartDateTime, ScheduleDurationMinutes, vc_UserID,vc_StatusID)
VALUES ('Finally done with sprocs', DATEADD(n, -45, GETDATE()), 45,
        (SELECT vc_UserID FROM vc_User WHERE UserName = 'tardy'),
        (SELECT vc_StatusID FROM vc_Status WHERE StatusText='Started')
       )

 SET @newVC = @@identity

 SELECT * 
 FROM vc_VidCast 
 WHERE vc_VidCastID = @newVC

 EXEC vc_FinishVidCast @newVC

 SELECT * FROM vc_VidCast WHERE vc_VidCastID = @newVC
```

I get an error:

> Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure vc_FinishVidCast, Line 179
>   Procedure or function 'vc_FinishVidCast' expects parameter '@finished', which was not supplied.

Comment: Not readable! Please indent.

Comment: I have improved the formatting

Comment: EXEC vc_FinishVidCast @newVC line needs a second parameter which you have not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like below:

```
DECLARE @Finished_ID INT
SELECT @Finished_ID = vc_StatusID FROM vc_Status WHERE StatusText='FInished'

EXEC vc_FinishVidCast @newVC,@Finished_ID
```